# Subquery in criteria - translate mysql into yii CActiveDataProvider with same table

Tags: mysql, yii

How would this translate into the yii CActiveDataProvider structure?!

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM data t1
WHERE t1.date= (SELECT MAX(t2.date)
 FROM data t2
 WHERE t2.fromNumber = t1.fromNumber)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code: Untested. Please check.

Hope you have created model for this table. Replace your model name in the place of `Model_name`

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Model_name', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
             'condition'=>'t.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date)
                                     FROM data t2
                                     WHERE t2.fromNumber = t1.fromNumber)'
                       )
    )
    );
```

This worked:

```
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Data', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'t.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date)
                FROM data t2
                WHERE t2.fromNumber = t.fromNumber)'),
            ));
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!

Comment: Accepting answer will help other to find the better solution :-)

Comment: I thought I had already accepted it when I upvoted. Now done :)